# Trying to print dept name of PhD students in dept EXCEPT those majors taking College Geometry

Tags: mysql

Need help on what syntax could I use to find out the departments that have no majors taking a College Geometry course.

Here is the original question: 
For those departments that have no majors taking a College Geometry course, 
print the department name and the number of PhD students in the department.

I have come up with results showing all departments and the PhD students in the department, but cannot figure out what syntax to use to find out the departments that have no majors taking a College Geometry course. I used EXCEPT, NOT IN, and LEFT JOIN, but am not getting what I'm looking for. Any advice..

Here are my tables:

```
Student(sid,sname,sex,age,year,qpa)
Dept(dname,numphds)
Prof (pname,dname)
Course (cno,cname,dname)
Major(dname,sid)
Section(dname,cno,sectno,pname)
Enroll(sid,grade,dname,cno,sectno)
```

Here is what my dept table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE dept (
 dname VARCHAR(100), 
 numphds INT
 );

INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Chemical Engineering', 32 );
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Civil Engineering', 88 );
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Computer Sciences', 47 );
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Industrial Engineering', 41 );
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Mathematics', 129 );
INSERT INTO dept VALUES ( 'Sanitary Engineering', 3 );
```

Here is what my course table looks like and it is the only table showing "College Geometry."

```
CREATE TABLE course (
 cno INT, 
 cname VARCHAR(100), 
 dname VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 302, 'Intro to Programming', 'Computer Sciences' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 310, 'Thermodynamics', 'Chemical Engineering' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 310, 'Intro to Garbage', 'Sanitary Engineering' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 365, 'City Planning', 'Civil Engineering' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 375, 'Highway Engineering', 'Civil Engineering' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 461, 'College Geometry 1', 'Mathematics' );
INSERT INTO course VALUES ( 462, 'College Geometry 2', 'Mathematics' );
```

Here is my code:

```
SELECT dept.dname, dept.numphds 
    FROM dept 
    LEFT JOIN course on course.dname = dept.dname LIKE 'College Geometry'
    GROUP BY dept.dname, dept.numphds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `where` clause and check for NULL condition on the `course` column

```
SELECT dept.dname, dept.numphds 
FROM dept 
LEFT JOIN course on course.dname = dept.dname  
and course.cname LIKE '%College Geometry%'
where course.dname is NULL
```

you can do the same with `not exists` clause

```
SELECT dept.dname, dept.numphds 
FROM dept 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( select 1 from  course 
  where course.dname = dept.dname 
  and course.cname LIKE '%College Geometry%'
)
```

Comment: I forgot about "WHERE" and "IS NULL." Perfect! Thank you so much!